# Bootsrap site displays fine on desktop, but mobile does not load at all

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, web-hosting

So I've uploaded a site built with bootstrap to my clients' domain. I tested the site on my personal domain first http://chacelyon.com/windward , which loads just fine on mobile and desktop. However, on my clients domain,when trying to view the site on my phone, a galaxy S5, it does not load at all.

My client had a wordpress site previously installed on their domain which got hacked. I'm not sure of the implications of this but I deleted all the wordpress files from their public html folder. Should I also delete their database too?

Can somebody please give me some insight as to why this is not working on my clients domain?

My clients domain is http://windward-performance.com

Comment: Hey. I have just tested this website on my Samsung Galaxy and it's look fine for me. Are you sure that everything is fine with this S5? Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Works all right, did you do a hard refresh?

Comment: even i do find it working on a nexus 5!
its working 'all fine'!

Comment: Do the pictures load and can you navigate through the links? My phone doesn't load any pictures and I've tried chrome and firefox on my s5.